# Draw labels with split normal and italic faces in euler plot (eulerr)

Tags: r, eulerr

The `eulerr` library produces a plot with the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eulerr)

matrix(data = c(T,T,T,F,T,F,T,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,T), ncol=3) %>%
  venn %>%
  plot(
    labels = c(
      "Left",
      "Right",
      "Oh, right"),
    main = expression("Oh,"~italic("right"))
       )
```

[image]

I need to have italic font in the labels, but only partially. I would like the third label to be formatted like the title: Oh, *right*.

I have tried a variety of permutations of `paste`, `expression`, `bquote`, `substitute`, while setting `label =` but to no avail.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `getGrob` and `setGrob` to replace the text after the venn diagram plot has been created.

```
library(eulerr)

mat <- matrix(data = c(T,T,T,F,T,F,T,F,T,T,T,F,F,F,T), ncol=3)

v <- venn(mat)

p <- plot(v,
  labels = c(
    "Left",
    "Right",
    "Oh, right"),
  main = expression("Oh,"~italic("right"))
)

p

gg <- getGrob(p, "tag.label.3")
gg[[1]] <- expression(bold("Oh,"~bolditalic("yes!")))
setGrob(p, "tag.label.3", gg)
```

[image: venn plot with changed label]

**Edit**: To find the grob that needs to be edited, you can use something like `grid.ls`:

```
library(grid)

grid.ls(p)
```

This will list the names of grobs in your plot, including `tag.label.3`:

```
euler.diagram
  main.grob
  canvas.grob
    diagram.grob.1
      fills.grob.1
      fills.grob.2
      fills.grob.3
      fills.grob.4
      fills.grob.5
      fills.grob.6
      fills.grob.7
      edges.grob
      tags
        tag.number.1
          tag.label.1
          tag.quantity.1
        tag.number.2
          tag.label.2
          tag.quantity.2
        tag.number.3
          tag.label.3
          tag.quantity.3
        tag.number.4
          GRID.null.1
          tag.quantity.4
        tag.number.5
          GRID.null.2
          tag.quantity.5
        tag.number.6
          GRID.null.3
          tag.quantity.6
        tag.number.7
          GRID.null.4
          tag.quantity.7
```

By trial/error, I found that `tag.label.3` was the desired text.

In addition, looking at the `eulerr` package, you have:

```
# from tag-grobs.R in eulerr package
labels_grob <- textGrob(
  label,
  x = unit(x, "native"),
  y = unit(y, "native"),
  rot = labels$rot[data$labels_par_id],
  gp = labels$gp[data$labels_par_id],
  name = paste0("tag.label.", data$labels_par_id)
)
```

Where `tag.label.` is used as a prefix for the text labels.

Comment: I've accepted this, but it would be good if you could expand your answer to explain the accesion of the `tag.label.` part. How did you know how or identify or access this attribute specifically by that name?

Comment: @steve_b My apologies, I should have added more explanation. I admit, this did take some searching, including in the `eulerr` package. Please see my edited answer with more details.

Comment: That is super useful and informative beyond this particular question- thanks for the extra detail!